# How to count number of occurance of character in each string in java?

Tags: java, string, character

Here I have code which prints single character count but I want each character occurrence of times. My code looks like this:

```
String s = "abdsd3$asda$asasdd$sadas";
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (s.charAt(i) == '$') {
        counter++;
    }
}
out.println("$ Occurence:" + counter + "times");`
```

The output I want is: a:7, b:1, d:6, s:6, $:3 times.
Can anybody help me? Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel,here just i have written to count $ count,but i dont know to count all characters count

Comment: can anybody tell me why vote down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that a character is an unsigned integral type (i.e. a number) with the range of 0..65535. If you know that all your characters are in the range 0..127, i.e. the first group of UNICODE code points which includes all digits, letters of Latin alphabet in both cases, and many common special characters, you can make an array of counters:

```
int[] counts = new int[128];
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char ch = s.charAt(i);
    if (ch < 128) {
        counts[ch]++;
    } else {
        System.err.println("Character is out of range: "+ch);
    }
}
```

Now you can print the counts as follows:

```
for (char c = 0 ; c < 128 ; c++) {
    if (counts[i] != 0) {
        System.out.println(c + " : " + counts[c]);
    }
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/onpIfr)

Comment: dasblinkenlight,could you please run your code,it is showing some additional special characters also.

Comment: @GangadharB It shows them with zero counts, right? That's because a zero check was missing.

Comment: As a rule, my answer with sorting of array should be used, as generally you cannot make such assumptions about the characters range

Answer (score 1):

**Beautiful one line solution using stream api:**

```
    Arrays.stream(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().replace(" ", "").chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c) //toCharArray returns primitive array
            .toArray(Character[]::new))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ", " + v));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, sort the characters in the string, using

```
char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

Now, when arr is sorted just do what you did previously to count, starting the counter from zero when the character in place i is different from arr[i-1]:

```
public class CountChars {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "abdsd3$asda$asasdd$sadas";
        char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
        java.util.Arrays.sort(arr);
        int cnt = 0;
        final char UNDEF = (char)-1;
        char c = UNDEF, prev = UNDEF;
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length;++i){
            c = arr[i];
            if(c!=prev){
                if(prev!=UNDEF){
                    System.out.println("The character '" +prev + "' occurs " + cnt +" times");
                }
                prev = c;
                cnt = 1;
            }else{
                cnt++;
            }
        }
        if(c!=UNDEF){
            System.out.println("The character '" +c + "' occurs " + cnt +" times");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> h = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    String s = "abdsd$asda$asasdd$sadas";

    for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {

        if ((h.containsKey(ch))) {

            h.put(ch, h.get(ch) + 1);

        } else {

            h.put(ch, 1);

        }
    }

    for (char key : h.keySet()) {

        System.out.println(key + "-" + h.get(key));

    }
}
```